# Problema de insert usando Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, formularios, visual-studio-2013

Como se mira en la imagen, me indica que envio nulo en dpi[image: problema]

pero estos campos los he llenado correctamente en el form [image: ui]

Alguna solucion al respecto

**En la tercera imagen puedne ver completo como lo he manejado**

[image: vista completa]

**Codigo de insert**

```vb
Private Sub GuardarToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GuardarToolStripMenuItem.Click

    ''1 ---------creamos linea vacia 
    Me.registro = dtparticipantes.NewparticipantesRow
    ''obtener datos del formulario y asignarlos a registro columna

    ''2 ---------asignamos datos a linea
    Me.registro.dpi = Integer.Parse(txtdpi.Text)
    Me.registro.nombres = txtnombres.Text
    Me.registro.apellidos = txtapellidos.Text
    Me.registro.edad = Integer.Parse(txtedad.Text)
    Me.registro.sexo = txtsexo.Text
    Me.registro.federacion = Integer.Parse(txtfederacion.Text)
    ''Me.registro.equipo = Integer.Parse(txtequipo.Text)

    ''3 ---------agregar registro al dataTable
    dtparticipantes.AddparticipantesRow(Me.registro)

    ''4 ---------actualizamos la base de datos enviando el dataTable
    taParticipantes.Update(dtparticipantes)

End Sub
```

He estado probando y el problema en si es el siguiente:

1. estoy convirtiendo el textBox en entero y al mandarlo a la base de datos es Bigint
2. Por alguna razón no me deja ingresar ese entero en el campo y eso me pasa con todos los campos tipo bigInt de mi base de datos.

Aca esta la imagen de mi tabla en Sql Server

[image: Tabla sql server]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49109/discussion-on-question-by-vicete-geovanny-franco-siles-problema-de-insert-usando).

Answer (score 2):

- El problema principal radica en que use mi pk como campo de ingreso y
  lo he corregido agregando una columna adiciona llamada real_id para
  agregar el id de la persona.
- El problema secundario surgió al intentar parsear un dato nulo cuando
  dejaba vació el campo de equipo, entonces se soluciono validando para
  que permita enviar nulo.

Me disculpo al quitar su tiempo, pero no es razón para enojarse y darle un punto negativo a la pregunta, si es que es algo incomprensible pueden pedir que explique mejor el punto que esperan sea el problema.

Mas adelante mostrare la imagen final

Comment: `pero no es razón para enojarse y darle un punto negativo a la pregunta` esa no es la razón para votar negativamente tu pregunta, pero no te preocupes por la reputación; a medida que vayas navegando por Stack Overflow en Español podrás aprender a formular las preguntas de una manera mas clara y de acuerdo a los estándares del sitio. Por favor lee: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Vicete, te saludo y te comento que además de lo comentado por Mauricio, **es importante que revises la ayuda acerca de como crear una pregunta [ask] y como crear una respuestas [answer]**, de esta forma además de contribuir con tu conocimiento puedes ayudar a otros desarrolladores